# Import of .csv file from linux to windows MYSQl

Tags: python, mysql, linux, shell

I need a shell script that must import latest ".csv" file into mysql...

My case is--->i need to import the latest ".csv" file from linux to windows mysql i.e my ".csv" files will be stored in a path of linux PC and import need to be done in windows.
I would appreciate the prompt response.

Comment: How do you know what is "latest"? Did you try something yourself? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Hello Mr.Khalid...i hope you have answer for my question after viewing your profile...please let me know whether you can help me or not.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

shell script
ok:

```
step 1: sort the csv file by reverse date
        ls --time-style=full-iso -l | grep -E "*.csv" | sort -k5 -k6 -r
step 2: the first file is the latest file
step 3: there should have some tool to import csv file to mysql
```

windows or linux is not the problem, that's why you can also access window's mysql from linux.
just connect the ip:port address. then do anything you want

Comment: i am already having a shell script that imports .csv to windows mysql.just i need to modify,so that it has to fetch the latest file automatically.

Comment: step 1 is what you want.

Comment: yes...exactly Zuckonit..since i am not good at scripting, i cant modify my code with solution you provided..below is my code..can you plz suggest me the same.

Comment: SH_NAME="loadmysql_hti"
FEC_LOG_EJEC=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
SQL_NAME=LOAD_DATA_MYSQL
LOG_EJEC="./log/${SH_NAME}_$FEC_LOG_EJEC.log.ejec"

echo >> ${LOG_EJEC}

echo "Executing SQL:"${SQL_NAME}.sql 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOG_EJEC}

HOST=192.*.*.*
PORT=3306
USER=root
PASS*****
DB=mydb

echo "Starting Load data to DB: $DB" 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOG_EJEC}

#Ejecutamos la integracion en la BD
ERROR=`mysql --host=$HOST --port=$PORT --user=$USER --password=$PASS $DB --local-infile < ${SQL_NAME}.sql 2>&1`